# Java | variable-length argument vs. passing an array

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Are there some benefits of using variable-length arguments instead of just passing an array to method in Java. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Add the relevant code and the context.

Comment: Ok. I would say, in which case one is better than the other?

Comment: It's just syntactic sugar; but remember that you can also pass an array to a method declared with a variable-length argument.

Comment: The main benefit is for readability purposes. Although things become less readable as you add more parameters! It is down to personal choice, but I would say a method accepting 10 parameters is certainly not benefiting from ease of readability. I would even go as far as to say 5 parameters is becoming hard to read.

At this point, and probably before, you want to convert those parameters into a single object (probably not an array though).

Comment: Also, it is a question of extensibility / flexibility, as you can easily add parameters as fields to a single object, rather than having to refactor all the calls to the method. So if your code is in constant flux, this may be the better way to go after all.

Comment: (I'd written all that already but then someone closed the question to new answers so I though I would post it here anyway :-)